# Scrapy - Error while creating project - DDL Load failed

Tags: python, scrapy

**I am trying for a longer time.Please do help.**
I installed scrapy using conda.
I tested **pip show scrapy** in the command line and it is working perfectly.
While i type **import scrapy** in the python terminal it is not showing any error.
But if i create a project or execute an existing project of scrapy i get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\deploy.py:16: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.command` is deprecated, use `scrapy.commands` instead
  from scrapy.command import ScrapyCommand
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 252, in __init__
    log_scrapy_info(self.settings)
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\log.py", line 149, in log_scrapy_info
    for name, version in scrapy_components_versions()
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 35, in scrapy_components_versions
    ("pyOpenSSL", _get_openssl_version()),
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 43, in _get_openssl_version
    import OpenSSL
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "C:\Users\Nikeshh\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

I am using **scrapy startproject tutorial** to create a project.How to solve this error?
Is there any specific way to execute the scrapy code?
Even when i add openssl using conda i am getting the same error

Comment: What is the OS?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the OpenSSL libraries that are used for encryption.

You could go and download these from somewhere here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Alternatively I think the installer for git will install OpenSSL by default, which you can get here: https://git-scm.com/download

However, since you're using Anaconda, OpenSSL should also be available with conda: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/openssl

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which possible solution did you try?